# How to display data from currently logged in user

Tags: php, database, session

I'm newbie in php coding. Just start it a few weeks ago. I am making login, register and profile pages. I have a problem to display username that currently logged in. I tried all reference or tutorial and other forums. but still not working. Someone, please help me to solve.

Here is my **auth.php**

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])) header("Location: login.php");

?>
```

and the **login.php**

```
<?php 

require_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username OR email=:email";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $params = array(
        ":username" => $username,
        ":email" => $username
    );

    $stmt->execute($params);

    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Registered
    if($user){
        // verifikasi password
        if(password_verify($password, $user["password"])){
            // Make Session
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
            //success and redirect
            header("Location: index.php");

        }
    }
}
?>
<!DoctypeHTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

[P.S = Sorry for my english]

Comment: Is the whitespace before `<?php` in the code, or just a copy & paste error when creating the question?

Comment: Where are you attempting to display the username?

Comment: Props for using prepared statements, AND password_hash/verify. Those are two things more new coders completely overlook and do horribly wrong. (although I would never manipulate or filter a users password)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone error when paste.

Comment: Show index.php script

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `index.php`, write these lines.

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    echo $_SESSION['user']->fieldName; // here you need to retrieve fields
  }
```

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object online 40. what should i write sir?

Comment: can you do `print_r` in this if condition and you will know that whats exactly field name you have

Comment: send me your file at ping@naveedramzan.com

Comment: sended sir @Naveed

Comment: Yup got it. Just saw email, I will update. Sorry for late